# Google's voice search speech recognition service

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Google has speech recognition services available for use from mobile phones (Android has it built in, iPhone users can use the Google application) - http://www.google.com/mobile/. We've found one article where someone tried to reverse engineer the service at http://waxy.org/2008/11/deconstructing_google_mobiles_voice_search_on_the_iphone/.

We want to better understand what is happening over the network when we use Android's RecognizerIntent.  Does anyone have any experience using this service over the web or know of other articles that may explain its workings?

Comment: This question may include helpful information - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361826/does-chrome-have-buil-in-speech-recognition-for-input-typetext-x-webkit-speec

Comment: There was a good post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip that dealt with this question and I believe the answer came from a Google employee.

Comment: See Accessing Google Speech API - http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read this presentation few weeks ago- http://www.abelski.com/courses/android/speechinput.pdf

The following link is a 3 mile high review of the Google Voice Server ....
http://www.google.co.jp/events/developerday/2010/tokyo/pdf/tt1-gruenstein.pdf

Comment: I'd still love to see more details, but these links are very good. Thanks.

Comment: The google.co.jp link is dead unfortunately. This might be the same one: http://www.slideshare.net/googledevjp/tt1-gruenstein

Answer (score -5):

Answer: just move your **.apk** file to your android phone it will work. Error is only occuring because we are trying to do in emulator