# Does Chrome have built-in speech recognition for "x-webkit-speech" input elements?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit, speech-recognition

I'm wondering how

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech speech />
```

Is there a speech recognition enging built into Chrome or is it accessing an underlying speech recognition facility in the operating system?

Comment: Hacker News submission where you are probably found that link: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1972855

Answer (score 13):

Yup, Chrome does speech recognition via Google's servers.  But there's no reason that other browsers couldn't choose to implement it differently (for example using some speech recognition facility in the OS).

Balu, your link is actually a bit out of date.  The latest Google proposal can be found here: http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/htmlspeech/2010/10/google-api-draft.html

Although speech recognition has been available in the Chrome dev channel for some time, it has *not* shipped yet and we're not yet sure when it will ship.  We definitely want people to play with the API and offer feedback on it, but we don't think it's quite ready for prime time yet.

Comment: There are serious privacy concerns here.

Answer (score 9):

According to the code it sends the audio data as a POST request to:

```
https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=chromium&lang=??&lm=??&xhw=??&maxresults=3
```

`lm` is `grammar` in the code, `xhw` is `hardware_info` which is optional according to a comment. The audio appears to be speex, x-speex-with-header-byte:

```
// Encode the frame and place the size of the frame as the first byte. This
// is the packet format for MIME type x-speex-with-header-byte.
```

It looks like it would be pretty trivial to modify the chrome code to use in your own app.

*Update:*

You also need to get a [speech recognition API key](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) and they are **limited to 50 requests per day**. There is no way to increase that limit - not even by paying.

Comment: Anyone know if Google are fine with this API being used directly by anyone, or if it's against terms & conditions? Thanks.

Comment: Does anybody know how "lm" (grammar) attribute works? W3C draft stated that grammar can be any URL to GRXML file but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6):

They are using their own API for speech recognition. Ex: sending a post request to there servers.

Answer (score 6):

There is an experimental fork of speexenc that can encode x-speex-with-header-byte MIME binary format, its referenced on the [QXIP Wiki](http://qxip.net/mediawiki/index.php/SIP-SIR#Speex_Issues) and is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/QXIP/Speex-with-header-bytes). Does the job fine by placing the size of the frame as the first byte of packets.

Answer (score 2):

Speech recognition is a proposal by Google. https://docs.google.com/View?id=dcfg79pz_5dhnp23f5

The feature ships with Chrome 8+ and it looks like it sends the data to google servers to perform the actual recognition.

Answer (score 2):

This feature now works on chrome 11 beta.

check this out..

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input

Answer (score 2):

This might be of interest https://github.com/taf2/speech2text  ruby bindings for the google speech to text API

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Chrome does have built-in speech support through WebKit; just look at the Google homepage (which now has a microphone to the right of the search box). I wonder, however, if the Chrome team is working on Omnibox speech support. After all, Chrome is a WebKit-based browser!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a working group that produced http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml+voice/ but I don't believe this is implemented in any browser except Opera.

Answer (score 0):

I just confirmed this on my Chrome Cr-48, it works.