# Force Google Chrome to use local speech recognition engine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, speech-recognition

For

```
<input type="text" x-webkit-speech speech />
```

[apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361826/does-chrome-have-buil-in-speech-recognition-for-input-type-text-x-webkit-speec/4365533#4365533), Google Chrome sends voice data to Google servers for the actual recognition. Is it possible to make it somehow use an engine on the same machine instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry no it is not.

If you really require this feature please raise an issue on http://crbug.com/new

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not sure if this could be called a bug.

Comment: That is where you also raise feature requests.