# I want to use google API (Voice commands) on my PC

Tags: speech

I want to use google API (Voice commands) on my PC but now I don't know, how to i begin that,Please someone to guide me about this and post some project for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that Google speech recognition is one of the best and that it is now available offline but in my experience,  is much more oriented to Android applications and web rather than Desktop ones. If what you want is to integrate speech recognition to a website, you could find some examples in the [Web Speech API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html).

Now, if what you need is to incorporate speech recognition to desktop applications I would recommend Microsoft's speech recogntition, Nuance or Sphynx.

[Please also see this useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721436/google-speech-api)