# Android: Accessing the microphone simultaneously (RecognizerIntent + own app)

Tags: android, speech-recognition

my app uses the RecognizerIntent to record the user's voice and doing some speech recognition.

Now, I'd like to compare the results to some open source speech recognition engines. Most of them take an audio file as input. My thought was, to capture the sound from the Android's microphone, and start the RecognizerIntent at the same time. But it seems, that accessing the microphone is exclusive.

1. Is it possible to use the RecognizerIntent with a recorded audio stream?
2. Is it possible to access the microphone simultaneously with two Activites?

Comment: Did you solved this problem if so please guide me how to tackle it.

Comment: @Herr K did you end up doing it somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [record/save audio from voice recognition intent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047433/record-save-audio-from-voice-recognition-intent)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have tried to find a solution to the same problem and have not had success. One other approach we explored was to access the web service that Google uses for recognition. I posted a question at [Google's voice search speech recognition service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055830/googles-voice-search-speech-recognition-service), but it still goes unanswered.

There was a good post at [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip) that dealt with this question and I believe the answer came from a Google employee.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer to both of your questions is **no**, but there are plans to extend this for Gingerbread and 3.0: http://www.mobiclue.com/android-3-0-gingerbread-features-supported-phones.html

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that is possible to use RecognizerIntent and save the audio, the question is how?

You can see in Google Keep Android applications doing it once you click in the microphone.