# Android: record and convert speech to text

Tags: android

I want to use speech to text but if the result is not good, I want to use save the audio? If the result is reasonably good then the user will select to save text notes if not they will will select to save original audio. I don't want users to rerecord. I want to use the audio from speech to text. Let me know if any of you know how I could achieve this?

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this as well. So far, in my limited testing, I am unable to do it simultaneously. The recording will work but I get an error with the speech to text piece. It may have to be done in two steps. First record and then turn the recording into text.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this was addressed here.

[Android: Accessing the microphone simultaniously (RecognizerIntent + own app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669047/android-accessing-the-microphone-simultaniously-recognizerintent-own-app)

Comment: Thanks Doug. It help shed some lights into the mystery.

Comment: I think we may have to wait until Gingerbread gets more widely deployed.

Comment: http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/index.php I didn't try it yet but heard its good... I don't know if it would serve your needs.