# Match PCM data to previously entered data through mic or use as word recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am working on an application for recognizing speech from pcm data. Currently I am printing the pcm buffer.

```
int N = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

recorder = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, 8000, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N*10);

track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 8000, 
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,     N*10, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            recorder.startRecording();

            /*
             * Loops until something outside of this thread stops it.
             * Reads the data from the recorder and writes it to the audio track f
             */
            while(!stopped)
            { 
                //Log.i("Map", "Writing new data to buffer");
                short[] buffer = buffers[ix++ % buffers.length];
                N = recorder.read(buffer,0,buffer.length);
                for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i ++) {
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(buffer[i]));
                }
            }
```

I would like to either 1) have the pcm data be matched to previous pcm data or 2) have it be recognized as a word. For example. If I say 'hello' inside the mic, it turns the pcm data into the word hello and I can process according to the word or if I record a 'hello' and a 'world' in two separate buffers, then say 'hello' again, it can determine that I repeated the 'hello' and not the world. Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

Android has built in speech recognition. However, I don't believe it supports recorded PCM data. To use it, I believe, you must take voice input directly. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/03/speech-input-api-for-android.html to get started.

If you must have recorded data, you could use other services to do speech recognition. For an intro to some of the choices see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6351055/90236.

If you are just playing (and not building a production app), you could also try using the Google services for speech recognition that Chrome uses. You'd have to convert from PCM to FLAC. See [Google's voice search speech recognition service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055830/googles-voice-search-speech-recognition-service)

If you want to compare PCM buffers without doing recognition, signal processing is a deep and interesting field. Sorry, I'm too rusty to give any advice in that realm.