# Android: Where is Speech Recognition temp audio file saved?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

When I press and hold the search key on my Droid it starts the built in Android voice recognition.

While it is listening, if I speak the words "Note to self" and then keep talking, when done I get an email ready to send complete with the STT translation and the amr encoded audio file as an attachment.

I want to include this same functionality in my own program. More specifically, I need access to the audio file that is (or appears to be) created by speechrecognizer.

How do I access this audio file?

I am using api level 7. If I try to record and use speechrecognizer at same time it fails.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I was all confused, but now I realize the "note to self" is a special voice action as described in http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/

Comment: Try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463875/how-does-google-keep-do-speech-recognition-while-saving-the-audio-recording-at-t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the com.google.android.voicesearch application provides access to the recorded audio files.  The files are temporarily stored in /data/data/com.google.android.voicesearch/files after the user makes a recording, but I'm not sure how you would get read access to those files.