# convert Speech Voice to Text without use default UI ANDROID

Tags: android, voice, speech, dictation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Speech to Text from own sound file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file)

I have a application that recorded a file in wav format and convert it to mp3 format.

So I need to interpret this file and write it in a text file.

I'm thinking of using speech voice but I don't know how use it without UI default and delete automatic stop.

Basically I need record and write things that user dictated to my app also the application let him edit file. I need to help with the part of write my record in text file, any idea?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Checkout this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying to do since into the app but if not it's possible, I'm going to try with new alternatives, I would like to use jelly and its new speech services