# Speech recognition for recorded audio files in .3gp or wav format

Tags: android, speech-recognition, audio-recording, speech-to-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

I am developing an Android app which will record audio to a file, and then use speech recognition to get text from the recorded speech.

Is there a speech recognition library available for this sort of task?  How can I get started?

Answer (score 1):

Get start with this tutorial where you can learn speech to text conversion in Android with it's [speech API](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-speech-to-text-api/)

Also see:

- [Speech to Text from own sound file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file)
- [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)