# How to use Androids' speech to text with audio sample file

Tags: android, audio, speech-to-text

I was able to run an example project which uses Android speech to text using this code:

```
   private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

This works fine, but I was wondering, is it possible to use speech to text with an audio sample (byte array?) instead of recorded voice?

kind regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

Comment: please did you get this to successfully work? The methods described below seem to be deprecated and i wanted to know if there is a current way this can be done.

Comment: @nonybrighto did you figure out a way to do it? i'm stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 4):

Currently Android only supports RecognizerIntent

Have a look at all these questions...

[Speech recognition for recorded audio files in .3gp or wav format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092834/speech-recognition-for-recorded-audio-files-in-3gp-or-wav-format)

[Speech to Text from own sound file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file)

[Saving audio input of Android Stock speech recognition engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583406/saving-audio-input-of-android-stock-speech-recognition-engine)

[Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)