# how to give an audio file as input to the google speech to text api?

Tags: android, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

currently i made a 'speechtotext' app using the google speech to text api.

It takes whatever i speak near the mic as an input and displays the text form of it by sending it to google and getting the result from it.

Well,instead of speaking,i want to give an audio file as the input(which i have previously recorded using 'sound recorder' app) to my "speech to text" app.

This audio file is present in the sdcard of the phone.

Google speech to text api should choose this audio file as the input and then give its text form as the output.

I have pasted my "100% working" code of the xml and the java files for your references.

my xml file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="@drawable/superim"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:text="@string/tap_on_the_button_to_speak_"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
        android:layout_width="253dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/speak"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.38"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
          />

</LinearLayout>
```

my java file:

```
package com.prann.speechtotextdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
//import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private TextView txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    txtText.setText("");
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "YOUR DEVICE DOESNT SUPPORT SPEECH TO TEXT \n install google vocie search ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                txtText.setText(text.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do what i want to do ?? if so,how can it be done ?????

A detailed explanation would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Androids' speech to text with audio sample file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849379/how-to-use-androids-speech-to-text-with-audio-sample-file)

Comment: Better duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip