# Audio file to speech-to-text android engine

Tags: android, api, speech-to-text

I would the android speech-to-text system analyze an audio file instead a normal microphone flow, is it possible?

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18849379/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Androids' speech to text with audio sample file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849379/how-to-use-androids-speech-to-text-with-audio-sample-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is ofcourse possible. Take a look at Google Cloud Speech, it accepts a local audio file or better, an URL to that audio file.

[Here is offical docs](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize).