# Android Speech Recognition API on pre-recorded audio?

Tags: android

I know I can use the Android SpeechRecognizer API for speech recognition, but that API is meant for pressing a button, saying something, and then having it spit the text out. I'm wondering if there's a way to use a pre-recorded file (3gp) on the device and run that through some built-in library. All of my searches have only brought up the SpeechRecognizer, which can't use audio files.

Comment: Are you saying somehow take pre-recorded audio and have the speech recognition API interpret that audio file to a String?

Comment: @26hmkk That's my goal, correct.

Answer (score 0):

As I have found, it isn't possible with android's API, but there may be a way around it.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file) url.

EDIT:
I haven't tested it myself, it doesn't really look like it's supported, but check the link I guess.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, Google has restricted this now

Comment: Sorry, I guess Google doesn't wish to let devs have access to it... Very interesting question though!