# Convert pre-recorded file into Text using Google Speech Api in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

Using google speech Api we can convert Speech to text using given [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech). But I already have an Audio file and I want that file to be converted into text. Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speech to Text from own sound file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989981/speech-to-text-from-own-sound-file)

Comment: @KartikSharma That does not have a perfect solution. It's a workaround. In updated google speech API it is possible to do that without any workarounds. But there is no documentation provided.

Answer (score -1):

**When u click on Speech button that time call**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
```

I think it will help you

Comment: Sorry this is not what I am looking for. I need to this for already recorded file.

Comment: whenever u can recording file that time u can convert into text using above code

Comment: But i already have an audio file. I want to convert that audio file into text.