# How to simulate audio input to Microphone using .wav file

Tags: android, audio, wav, microphone, voice

My target is to use a `.wav` file as a substitute for microphone input in the Emulator. The `.wav` file has to be recognized and processed by the Speech Recorder in the Android emulator.

I want to test the Speech Recorder by giving voice commands from the `.wav` file, as if the app had received them through the microphone input.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful or not, but on non-android systems you could use a Loopback Driver. On OSX and Linux you can use Jack Audio or Soundflower for this. Maybe searching for an android equivalent of those might lead to something?