# android code to pick the voice through call

Tags: android, voice-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there is any android code to pick the voice from the other side in the call?
meaning while I'm speaking with another person in my Phone I can Play a speaker that picks the voice, can I direct this voice to my application to record, recognize it, or convert to text?
Since my target is to convert the voice in the call to text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Broadcast Receiver to handle calls

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){


    }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK){
        //apply recording here


    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
        //stop recording

    }

}
```

To convert Voice to Text Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

Answer (score 0):

You can record from [AudioSource.VOICE_DOWNLINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html). Keep in mind though that this might not work on every single Android phone out there, and that voice call audio is quite heavily compressed and therefore might not give you any good results from a Speech-To-Text engine.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But the recorder is not exactly what I want. I want to pick the voice of the other end through the call, mean for example when you call me in Phone I want to pick your voice programmatically in my app.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick"? To me it sounds like what you want to do is to record the voice call downlink. If you use the AudioRecord class you can call its `read()` method repeatedly to get more audio data into a buffer which you can then process.

Comment: I mean that I'm not want to record the call I want the conversation  from speech to text is doing during the conversation time (currently). my target is to help deaf people to do a call with other peoples by the speech to text recognizer during the call duration. not recording

Comment: You can do that with the approach I suggested. The AudioRecord class lets you read audio data from the specified source into a buffer (that you can e.g. feed into a speech to text engine). It won't save the audio data to a file. On phones released in the North American market there should already be support for TTY which is suitable for deaf and/or mute people, although it requires a special accessory.

Comment: OK, I got your mean. Thanks you so much.