# Passing .wav or any audio file to SpeechRecognizer in Android 4.2, 4.3

Tags: android, audio, speech-to-text

guys,

it looks like the similar question, but let me explain the biggest issue.

I need to pass pre-recorded .vaw files to Recognition engine. Not to web-based voice Recognition (as somebody suggests), it should work also in offline mode.

I'm not sure that Google allows this, but I see the following API:

```
public static SpeechRecognizer createSpeechRecognizer (Context context, ComponentName serviceComponent)
```

where I do not see what is the *service component*.

Intents, used by recognition service, does not provide audio streams. So looks like .wav file should be substituted for SpeechRecognizer somewhere in this API.

Thanks,
Dmitry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

Comment: Not exactly. I just want to check, if somebody has opportunity to feed Recognized from diffrent audio stream (not mic)

Comment: @DmitryRagozin did you get the solution?

Comment: did you solve this?