# SpeechRecognition API: How to get the voice features (MEL Coefficients)

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, mfcc

I was going to implement a speaker verification app for Android, and was wondering if there would be a way to get the voice features (MEL Coefficients) from the Android's Speech Recognition module?

Please note that speaker verification is slightly different than speech recognition, so that's why I'm not using the speech recognition directly.

Comment: You can extract MFCC by using such as CMUSphinx if you have audio. But you don't get the audio from Speech Recognition module at this time. for more detail, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not compute MFCC from audio stream with Android API. You can use external library for that, for example [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)

You can also try existing Java-only libraries for voice verification for Android like 
[Recognito](https://github.com/amaurycrickx/recognito)

Comment: It's honor to see you here, Nikolay Shmyrev.