# Voice Recognition with an audio file?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am currently working on an app that would require recording the audio within my app and then sending the clip to google for transcription.
Is there any way I can send an audio clip to be processed with speech to text?
Or is there any other way other than this to convert that recording to text ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)

Answer (score 3):

Google's Voice To Text API is not available publicly at the moment and there's no announcement on where it could become available. On Android you can use system voice recognition feature, but it will only transcribe what it records by itself and your won't be able to feed it with any audio file for processing.

As for now, you either need to use other services like AT&T's, IBM's Watson, Dragon Dictation (all are on-line) or maybe consider including Sphinx CMU into your app if you absolutely demand off-line solution.