# Can i convert an mp3 file to text in ANDROID?

Tags: android, text, mp3

does Android support the capability of 
converting an mp3 file that includes speech into their appropriate words and then write the results in TextView or Toast or anything??

I am not talking about using Speech Recognizer!!
i mean the file in mp3 has to be picked from sd 
not recorded and analyzed in realtime
??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue as yours. I changed my speech API from Google to Bing(Microsoft-Bing speech API). Bing speech API has well documentation for Android Studio and they are also giving sample code.
[Link for Bing Speech API](http://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android)

Answer (score 1):

With the android SDK you can't.

But you can send audio files to the Google Speech API and receive a response from it.
https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160

For example, you can see this workaround.
http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/

Also recommend this.
[Voice recognition on android with recorded sound clip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip)