# Is there a way to send audio bytes to SpeechRecognizer

Tags: android, audio, accessibility, android-speech-api

So I'm trying to make an app accessible for deaf/HoH people and so far I'm able to get the **audio bytes** that is being currently played in the app (I think).

<s>The thing is, **can I use this SpeechRecognizer to send the audio bytes and get the text results?**</s>

<s>Couldn't find a method for this and I'm wondering if I'm in the right library to perform this task.</s>

I looked up for Speech APIs and I couldn't find nothing for free (obviously) so I'm looking in the android libraries.

Any information is helpful for me.

**Question edit:**
Is there any library or something that could do this `speech to text` f**rom audio bytes** or **any other information that need**?

Comment: Have you tried [AudioBytes](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/messages/audio/AudioBytes)?

Comment: coz' there's a method you can call `toMessage()`

Comment: SpeechRecognizer streams audio to remote servers to perform speech recognition and you can get the text via RecognitionListener#onResults(Bundle) and RecognitionListener#onPartialResults(Bundle) methods. You can use the startListening(Intent recognizerIntent) to start listening for speech. If you already have the audio bytes the SpeechRecognizer currently
doesn’t support any method to convert them to text.

Comment: Hey @MariosP I don't want to listen nothing I already got the audio bytes, I want this audio bytes to text, is that possible?

Comment: I took a look and I don't think that's what I'm looking for @Ric17101

Comment: @Barrufet check this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Android as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942196/can-i-convert-an-mp3-file-to-text-in-android and modify the code based on your needs.

Comment: Already tried to use it but I need an api key and probably set up some billing as they say it's only free for some months @MariosP

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> data = bundle.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
editText.setText(data.get(0));
```

See [this Medium post](https://medium.com/voice-tech-podcast/android-speech-to-text-tutorial-8f6fa71606ac) that goes into more detail.

Comment: I'm not using SpeechRecognizer, I want the audio bytes to text.