# How to extract text from an audio file

Tags: android

I am making an app that converts audio to text. I tried google's speech-to-text API, but it works when you press an icon it will recognize the voice same time, but I have an audio file which I want to convert to text.
I searched a lot, but I am getting only speech to text.

Answer (score 1):

You can using Google's Cloud Speech API.

Add this to your gradle file :

```
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-speech:0.30.0-alpha'
```

and use this code :

```
    // Instantiates a client
    SpeechClient speech = SpeechClient.create();

    // The path to the audio file to transcribe
    String fileName = "./resources/audio.raw";

    // Reads the audio file into memory
    Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
    byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

    // Builds the sync recognize request
    RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
        .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
        .setLanguageCode("en-US")
        .build();
    RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
        .setContent(audioBytes)
        .build();

    // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
    RecognizeResponse response = speech.recognize(config, audio);
    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

    for (SpeechRecognitionResult result: results) {
      // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
      // first (most likely) one here.
      SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
      System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
    }
    speech.close();
```

For more, refer this link : 
https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Answer (score 0):

May be you can find what you wanted from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip). There is a sample [github project](https://github.com/katchsvartanian/voiceRecognition/tree/master/VoiceRecognition) which you can refer to identify the workaround.